# Laravel. Class "Illuminate\Routing\Events\PreparingResponse" not found

Tags: php, laravel, cicd

I'm trying to deploy an app to prod, but I'm getting the following error:

Class "Illuminate\Routing\Events\PreparingResponse" not found

Locally everything works the same way. I am using docker and gitlab ci/cd.

I tried to find out what the gpt chat was up to, this is what he told me

In Laravel 10, the PreparingResponse class does not exist in the Illuminate\Routing\Events namespace." I just have Laravel 10.

Please tell me how can I solve this problem

Comment: GPT is wrong, PreparingResponse does exist in Illuminate/Routing/Events in Laravel 10. Make sure that `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Events/PreparingResponse.php` exists in production, and try both `composer update` and `composer dumpautoload` (though the first should also do the second). Other than that, we'd need to know more information, such as the code causing the issue and the full stack trace from the error.

Comment: Actually, poking around a bit more and while reading the latest update post, [PreparingResponse is added in 10.13 just yesterday](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-10-13-0). You definitely need to run `composer update`